# Handle notification dismiss action when app is on the background

Tags: swift, push-notification, background, dismiss

I'm trying to listen user clear push notification action. I've the code below, It's working when the app is on the foreground but when i put the app on the background it doesn't go into that function. Is there any way that i can do some coding when the user clear the notification on the background state?

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
  if(response.actionIdentifier == UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier){
            ...
            //I need to do some coding here!
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this for receiving remote notifications behind the scenes:

```
   extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
            // Process this userInfo dictionary
            processNotification(dictionary: userInfo)
        }
```

In my willFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate I call this:

```
   fileprivate func setupAPN(application: UIApplication) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        MobilePlatformPush.setRemoteDelegate(delegate: self)
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { _, _ in }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

}
```